# Apple Pay Sheet - difference between Contact name and Shipping name

Tags: ios, applepay

When submitting Apple Pay Sheet, `PKPayment` from `paymentAuthorizationViewController: didAuthorizePayment:` will give me shipping and billing details, depending on what I set in the `PKPaymentRequest`.

However, due to primitive testing (Apple Pay not launched in the UK), Stripe's basic ApplePaySheetStub and iOS9's issue with requesting PKAddressFieldName, I haven't been able to find out the answer to this question: In Apple Pay Sheet - what is the difference between the name under CONTACT section and name under SHIPPING section?

I can find name from SHIPPING section from `PKPayment`, but should name under CONTACT section be populated, where would I find that post-authorisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From talking to Apple, the name under CONTACT section will only appear if the payment request didn't include shipping Address field. In other words, PKAddressFieldPostalAddress & PKAddressFieldName can't be both requested for shipping.

Based on that explanation, you won't see name under contact and under shipping. Its one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] should name under CONTACT section be populated, where would I find that post-authorization

All the contact information along with shipping address is coalesced into a single ABRecordRef (`shippingAddress`) so you'd find it in there.

Comment: thanks - but what about name under shipping section. basically, there are two places for name, but I can only see one place to find it in ABRecordRef